# Error message: (Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails)

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I am doing on these two tables, which is accountinfo and userrecipeinfo

**accountinfo**

```
create table accountinfo 
(
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    username varchar(80), 
    password varchar(80), 
    name varchar(80),

    primary key (id)
);
```

**userrecipeinfo**

```
create table userrecipeinfo 
(
    recipeid int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    recipename varchar(80), 
    reciperating int, 
    recipephoto LONGTEXT, 

    primary key (recipeid), 
    foreign key (recipeid) references accountinfo(id)
);
```

However, when I try to insert one of the values

```
insert into userrecipeinfo (recipename, reciperating, recipephoto) 
values ('tom yum', 4, 'https://www.cbronline.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Trolling.jpg');
```

I get an error:

> ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`userinfo`.`userrecipeinfo`, CONSTRAINT `userrecipeinfo_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`recipeid`) REFERENCES `accountinfo` (`id`))

I would like to know what caused this error. Thanks!

Comment: you need a record in accountinfo with that id first

Comment: I got tried to insert one of the records in the accountinfo table, but the error message still pops up

Comment: It doesn't make sense for recipeid to be an auto_increment column and a foreign key.

Comment: (Clearly,) This is a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 1):

You are violating the foreign key constraint. When a foreign key is added it must match a existing value in the reference table.

In your case `userrecipeinfo.recipeid` refers to `accountinfo.id`, so when you insert a row into `userrecipeinfo`, there must be a corresponding row in `accountinfo` which matches `accountinfo.id = userrecipeinfo.recipeid`.

You can try `select * from accountinfo where id=4;` to see whether there is a row whose id is 4.